# Changing sort order with pre_get_posts using is_post_type_archive doesn't change category pages

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to change the sort order of staff members using post meta. This works just fine on the main staff archive page but I can't get it working on staff category archives. I've tried this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cd_sort_staff' );
     function cd_sort_staff( $query ) {
         if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'staff' ) {
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');  
            $query->set('meta_key', 'sort_order');  
            $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
    }
}
```

And this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cd_sort_staff' );
function cd_sort_staff( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('staff') ) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');  
            $query->set('meta_key', 'sort_order');  
            $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
    }
}
```

Both work fine on the main /staff/ archive page. But neither work on /staff_category/category-name the posts are sorted based on post date only.

Comment: Is this categories or terms from a custom taxonomy

Comment: It's a custom taxonomy archive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you need to target the post type archive page and taxonomy pages, you just need to extend your function to include the specific taxonomy archive pages. You can use [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) to target these taxonomy pages

You can try the following; (*You can just modify `is_tax()` to target specific taxonomies or terms according to documentation*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cd_sort_staff' );
function cd_sort_staff( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        if ( $query->is_tax() || $query->is_post_type_archive('staff') ) {
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');  
            $query->set('meta_key', 'sort_order');  
            $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest changing `is_post_type_archive('staff')` to `$query->is_post_type_archive` for consistency ;)

Comment: Thank you so much Pieter. This works perfect. I just expected is_post_type_archive('staff') to include all archives including taxonomy pages just like the archive-staff.php template works for both. Anyway thanks a ton.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic You can do that, it all depends if the OP has several custom post types and specifically just need to target one of those custom post types

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it worked out. Enjoy :-) @Daniel

Comment: Sorry, I meant keep the arguments the same, just call the method rather than the global function: `$query->is_post_type_archive( 'staff' )`

Comment: True, I agree with that. Copy and post mistake there. Thanks for pointing that out @TheDeadMedic

Comment: @Daniel One slight adjustment, see the updated code